# Using JS onMouseover to change opacity of image

Tags: javascript, opacity

I know this is possible to achieve much easier and quicker with CSS. I have done this but am trying to learn Javascript and was wondering why the following is not working? The idea being to set up a very basic event handler where moving the mouse over an image reduces the opacity of the image.

```js
function changeClass () {
    document.getElementByTagName("img").className += "hover"
}
    
img.onMouseover = changeClass();
```

```css
img {
    opacity:1;
}

img.hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="image_wrapper">
 <table id="image_table">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <img src="image1.gif" alt="image1" />
   </td>
            <td>
                <img src="image2.gif" alt="image2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are _calling_ your function, instead of assigning the _reference_ to it to the event handler attribute. `img.onMouseover = changeClass;` would be correct.

Comment: Btw., after the second mouseover you will end up with the element having a class `hoverhover`, and so on … so you should at least insert a space before the class name.

Comment: CBroe, Thank you. I didn't notice the mistake of calling the function as opposed to assigning and missing the space. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be

```
function changeClass () {
     var className = document.getElementByTagName("img").className;
     if(className.indexOf('hover') == -1) {
         //Only add the class name 1 time
         document.getElementByTagName("img").className += " hover"
     }
}

img.onMouseover = changeClass; //Pass the function as a callback
```